# How to force save and replace in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have been using `AccessMode and ConflictResolution` and it was fine for vba.

In vbs

```
ObjWB.SaveAs myFolder & "test.xlsx",  AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
```

throws `expected statement error` for character `: =`

How to save as and force replace in vbs ?

Answer (score 6):

VBScript doesn't support the `param:=value` feature of VB and VBA. You need to supply function params in their proper order. You can omit parameter values, however, if they're optional. It also won't have any of Excel's constants defined. You must define them yourself. Try the following:

```
Const xlExclusive = 3
Const xlLocalSessionChanges = 2

ObjWB.SaveAs myFolder & "test.xlsx", , , , , , xlExclusive, xlLocalSessionChanges
```

Calling a function this way can get confusing with the number of omitted params, however, so it's often useful to specify each param value on its own line (if you don't mind the extra lines of code):

```
ObjWB.SaveAs myFolder & "test.xlsx", _    ' Filename
             , _                          ' FileFormat
             , _                          ' Password
             , _                          ' WriteResPassword
             , _                          ' ReadOnlyRecommended
             , _                          ' CreateBackup
             xlExclusive, _               ' AccessMode
             xlLocalSessionChanges        ' ConflictResolution
```

Within the Visual Basic editor in Excel you can use the Object Browser (shortcut key = F2) to determine the values for constants defined by the Excel type library.