# With Excel, trying to find genuine used range from external HTA

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, hta

I've been using this command:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

But the UsedRange property can often be inaccurate. So I'm looking for an alternative. I found a great tip explaining this method:

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

This works a treat in Excel. However, I'm running code from an HTA, so I need to convert this line, and I'm struggling. THIS is my question --- please can someone offer guidance on how to convert this simple code into an HTA-compatible one?

Out of interest, to try to circumvent this problem, I tried writing a routine in a way that I understand. The result *works*, but is very slow. Here it is for giggles:

```
    Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application") 
    wb = "test.xlsx"
    objExcel.Workbooks(wb).Activate
    wbactiveSheet = objExcel.Workbooks(wb).ActiveSheet.Name

    'determine rows and columns in range of first xls
    theNumRow = objExcel.Workbooks(wb).Sheets(wbactiveSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    theNumCol = objExcel.Workbooks(wb).Sheets(wbactiveSheet).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'determine genuine used rows:
    x = 1 'start at first row
    blankRows = 0
    Do 'each row
        y = 1 'start at first column
        blankCells = 0
        Do 'each column
            If objExcel.Workbooks(wb).Sheets(wbactiveSheet).Cells(x, y).Value <> "" Then
                theNumRowActual = x
                'found non-blank, skip to next row
                Exit Do 'the columns loop
            Else
                blankCells = blankCells + 1
            End If
            y = y + 1
        Loop Until (y - 1) = theNumCol
        If blankCells = theNumCol Then 'blank row
            blankRows = blankRows + 1
            If blankRows = 50 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            blankRows = 0
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = theNumRow 'i.e. until the testing area matches the usedRange property

    'determine genuine used columns:
    y = 1 'start at first column
    blankCols = 0
    Do 'each column
        x = 1 'start at first row
        blankCells = 0
        Do 'each row
            If objExcel.Workbooks(wb).Sheets(wbactiveSheet).Cells(x, y).Value <> "" Then
                theNumColActual = y
                'found non-blank, skip to next column
                Exit Do 'the rows loop
            Else
                blankCells = blankCells + 1
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop Until (x - 1) = theNumRowActual
        If blankCells = theNumRowActual Then 'blank column
            blankCols = blankCols + 1
            If blankCols = 50 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            blankCols = 0
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Loop Until (y - 1) = theNumCol 'i.e. until the testing area matches the usedRange property
    'bug


    MsgBox "USEDRANGEMETHOD:" &vbNewLine & "rows: " & theNumRow & vbNewLine & "columns: " & theNumCol & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "NEWMETHOD:" & vbNewLine & "rows: " & theNumRowActual & vbNewLine & "columns: " & theNumColActual
```

Thank you

Comment: try this one: `LastRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), -4123, 2, 1, 2, False).Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already have your worksheet open and active? In that case:

```
Const xlByRows = 1
Const xlPrevious = 2

Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
LastRow = objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

See my [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822831/how-to-force-save-and-replace-in-vbscript/22824912#22824912) about using VBScript to call an Excel function for additional tips.

When you're programming using VBA within Excel then `Cells` is a native object that you can reference directly. But when you're *outside* of Excel -- in an HTA or WSH script -- your script has no idea what `Cells` refers to. The only Excel objects you have are the ones you create. So you must work your way down the chain, from your main Excel (`Application`) object to a workbook and then to a sheet before you can operate on the `Cells` property. It might make more sense if you use the same names Excel does:

```
' Define the same objects that Excel does...
Set Application = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set ThisWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' Now get a sheet based on its name ("Sheet1", in this example)..
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' And operate on the Cells collection...
MySheet.Cells.Find(...)
```

As a shortcut, Excel provides an `ActiveSheet` property that you can use directly on the `Application` object to get the current sheet, essentially bypassing the workbook layer. That's what I've used in my first code snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great explanation here and in your other linked answer. ~50 lines of code is replaced by 2 lines; a 15 second calculation now happens in the blink of an eye.