# VBscript: Copy/Paste data from one workbook to next blank row (specific cells) of another workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm just a newbie in VBscript (and code). I have a problem when trying to copy/paste data from one workbook to next blank row of another workbook using "Excel macro - VBA".

For example: I want to copy range from A2 to A4 (or more) of workbook 1 paste to A4 (blank row) of workbook 2. And copy range from C2 to C4 (or more) of workbook 1 paste to E4 (blank row) of workbook 2. I'm using "Do..Loop" method.

Here is my problem after executing the new answer code:

----------A-----------------E

1------Title  -------------Title

2------(BLANK)------------bbb1

3------aaa2 -------------**PasteC1** <- **(BLANK)** cell here has been replaced

4------PasteA1 ---------**PasteC2**

5------PasteA2 ---------**PasteC3**

6------PasteA2 ---------

7

I want it to be:

----------A-----------------E

1------Title  -------------Title

2------(BLANK) ------------bbb1

3------aaa2 ------------**(BLANK)**

4------PasteA1 --------**PasteC1**

5------PasteA2 --------**PasteC2**

6------PasteA2 --------**PasteC3**

7

It pasted the data from range A correctly, but from the "B" data, the code pasted data into next row compared with "A" data instead of pasting to the cell next to "A" data. I want the code pasted to the cell correctly. I think about "IF" or "FOR" statement but I have no ideas on this.

Here is my edited code with Dan's answer but the problem still exists:

```
'Copy "A" data
With srcWorksheet
    LastSrcRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With destWorksheet
    LastDestRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set srcRange = srcWorksheet.Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(10, 1), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 1))
srcRange.Copy
destWorksheet.Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 1), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 1)).Select
destWorksheet.Paste


'Copy "B" data
With srcWorksheet
    LastSrcRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With destWorksheet
    LastDestRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set srcRange = srcWorksheet.Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(10, 2), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 2))
srcRange.Copy
destWorksheet.Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 2), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 2)).Select
destWorksheet.Paste
```

I have researched on many sites but still not found out solution yet.

Please help me.

Thanks and forgive for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro in Excel to do this? That can be a good place to start. Then you can make some small changes to the code it generates to make it work via VBScript.

Comment: Dear Bond, I tried the recorded method already but this method couldn't detect and generate code for the "next blank row". I don't find any solutions for my question now. I updated the code follow Dan's answer but the problem still exist

Comment: @Skyoffeedom You can add your own snippet to find the next blank row. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897490/with-excel-trying-to-find-genuine-used-range-from-external-hta/22897808#22897808) post might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the following code, are you still getting the staggered Excel paste behavior?

```
Sub copy2excel()

Set sourceExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
sourceExcel.Visible = True
Set destExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
destExcel.Visible = True

'Open the source and the destination files
Set srcWorkBook = sourceExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Your\Filepath\Here.xls")
Set destWorkbook = destExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Your\OtherFilepath\Here.xls")

'Open the 1st sheet of source file
Set srcWorksheet = srcWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
'Open the 1st sheet of destination file
Set destWorksheet = destWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'copy all data
LastSrcRow = srcWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastDestRow = destWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set srcRange = Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(2, 1), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 2))
Set destRange = Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 1), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 2))
srcRange.Copy destRange

End Sub
```

--end revision--

Here is a slight adjustment to your code that forgoes the loop/activate/select/copy/paste in favor of using `range.copy`:

```
'Copy "A" data
With srcWorksheet
    LastSrcRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With destWorksheet
    LastDestRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set srcRange = Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(2, 1), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 1))
Set destRange = Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 1), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 1))
srcRange.Copy destRange

'copy "B" data
With srcWorksheet
    LastSrcRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With destWorksheet
    LastDestRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set srcRange = Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(2, 2), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 2))
Set destRange = Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 2), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 2))
srcRange.Copy destRange
```

Additionally, if you are sure that columns A and B will always be populated to the same row in your source file, you could accomplish the entire `range.copy` at one time:

```
'copy all data
LastSrcRow = srcWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastDestRow = destWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set srcRange = Range(srcWorksheet.Cells(2, 1), srcWorksheet.Cells(LastSrcRow, 2))
Set destRange = Range(destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, 1), destWorksheet.Cells(LastDestRow + LastSrcRow - 1, 2))
srcRange.Copy destRange
```

Comment: The above should do the trick and ran as expected inside Excel proper -- looking forward to your results @user3506810!

Comment: Dear @Dan Wagner, I got problems when running your script. Can you please give your idea with my answer (and problem) above.

Comment: What happens when you run the latest version (at the top of my answer)?

Comment: I added my problems in my answers below. The result doesn't meet my expectation. I edited the code a little bit and the issue still not fix. Please find my edited code in the answer below in this topic.

Comment: Your new answer are worked perfectly when pasting all copied data. But I have one question, if I want to "Copy" "A" and "C" from Source and "Paste" to "D" and "E" in Destination. How can it work? I think your first solution is more flexible.

Comment: Dear Dan Wagner, I tried your code again and it's worked perfectly. I find out why it didn't work the last time. Because my destination ranges are placed in a "Table" format. So the problem still exists because of the range in "Table" is different. I remove all "Table" format and it's worked like a charm. Thanks for your help and can you give me your idea with "Table" format?

Comment: Hey @Skyoffreedom, I did some searching on the MSDN website and found the following sections on `ListObject` and `ListColumn`. It turns out you can set a `range` to a `ListColumn.DataBodyRange`, which should result in a solution very similar to my code above. Check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273487(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Dear @Dan Wagner, thanks for your reply. I will check your link now.

Comment: Dear @Dan Wagner, thanks for your link. I got the "ListObject" from that and make my code correct by workaround method. I will remove "Table" format before pasting data and create "Table" again when finished. Thanks for you help so much.