# copying column from one excel to another

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have some specific requirement to copy B column each workbook and Paste them sequentially in Master work book.

e.g. WB1, WB2 Wb3 are the workbooks, and Master should have data following ways:

1. copy from WB1 data B3 onwards till value exists and paste to Matser workbook B3 column onwards
2. copy from WB2 data B3 onwards till value exists and paste to Master workbook C3 column onwards
3. copy from WB2 data B3 onwards till value exists and paste to Master workbook D3 column onwards

and so on for other workbooks

I am using VBS but unable to find any help for my requirement. Any help in this regard is much appriciated. Thanks in anticipation.

This is what I had been trying...

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set sourcewb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(SourceFilePath)
Set destwb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(DestFilePath)
objExcel.Visible = True
Set sourcews = sourcewb.Sheets(sourcesheet)
Set destws = destwb.Sheets(destsheet)
sourcews.Activate
Set SourceColumn = Selection.sourcews.Offset(3, 1).Range("B1").Select
Set TargetColumn = destws.Range("B3")
SourceColumn.Copy
```

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far

Comment: Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 set swb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(SFilePath)
 set dwb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(DFilePath)
 objExcel.Visible = True
 set sws = swb.Sheets(ssheet)
 set dws = dwb.Sheets(dsheet)
 set Rows = sws.Rows
 sws.Activate
 Set SourceColumn = Selection.sws.Offset(3,1).Range("B1").select
 Set TargetColumn = dws.Range("B3")
 SourceColumn.Copy

Comment: where are you going to use this code? From Excel workbook?

Comment: i am writing one VBS which will do this for me on excel workbook- Saket

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Selection.sourcews...` because VBScript has no clue what `Selection` is. The global `Selection` object only exists within Excel/VBA.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897490/with-excel-trying-to-find-genuine-used-range-from-external-hta/22897808#22897808) for more information on using Excel objects from VBScript.